# FCKeditor in jQuery ui dialog not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm having serious trouble getting this to work in IE7/8. In FF, everything works as expected.

When the user clicks on a certain link, a modal dialog popup is shown. In this dialog, there is a form, which contains one textarea, that is replaced with a FCK instance. The form is loaded from the server using ajax on the clientside and php on the serverside.

There's one strange way to get the FCK editor shown, and that is by resizing the dialog.

Library versions: 
jquery: 1.3.2
jquery ui: 1.7.3
FCKeditor: 2.6.1 build 19297

Any help would be strongly appreciated, I'm on a deadline here :-(

Comment: @Pekka I'm not getting any error messages. Both FCK and jquery ui dialog use iframes. My (intuitive) guess is that the conflict has something to do with this.

Comment: What is visible in IE then. Nothing, or the un-replaced textarea?

Comment: Could you link to a reproduction of the issue please?

Comment: I started using [jQuery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html).  I allways wanted to try it out, this was my opportunity, and I'm really glad I did. It's a very flexible toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a slight timeout on the FCK instance to insure the dialog is fully instantiated before the FCK instantiates.